# Can Videocalls and Chats be end-to-end encrypted in ConnectyCube?

Tags: encryption, connectycube

Can videocalls and textchats be end-to-end encrypted in ConnectyCube?
I could not find any indication on that on the website.
For example in Twilio, there is the following description:

end-to-end encryption: All media is routed Peer-to-Peer or via Twilio’s Global TURN infrastructure and secured using DTLS/SRTP. Twilio can never decrypt the media shared in a Peer-to-Peer Room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**End-to-end encryption for video calling**

ConnectyCube uses WebRTC which provides secure video calls out of the box via DTLS/SRTP which is mandatory in WebRTC.

Encryption is a mandatory feature of WebRTC and is enforced on all components - all media streams sent over WebRTC are securely encrypted, enacted through standardised and well-known encryption protocols.

So the same what is applied to Twilio can be applied to ConnectyCube.

There are lots of very useful information about WebRTC security is available at http://webrtc-security.github.io document

**End-to-end encryption for messaging**

ConnectyCube provides pluggable system so any end-to-end encryption libraries and solutions can be integrated on top of the ConnectyCube messaging system, for example:

- [OTR](https://otr.cypherpunks.ca/software.php)
- [OMEMO](https://conversations.im/omemo/) that adapts Signal Protocol to the XMPP world.
- [OLM](https://git.matrix.org/git/olm/about/docs/olm.rst)

Here is a guide how to use OTR on top of ConnectyCube https://developers.connectycube.com/guides/end-to-end-encryption-otr

Comment: Aweseome. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Do you know any tutorials or guidelines how OTR or OMEMO can be added to ConnectyCube textchat?

Comment: @StefanBadi I know they can advise on tech tutorials here https://connectycube.com/contact/

Comment: Here is guide to ConnectyCube end-2-end encryption https://developers.connectycube.com/guides/end-to-end-encryption-otr

Comment: Thank you. Great